# $\{ x,y \} \times \mathbb{R}$ not connected in the standard topology why?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, connectedness

I know that singletons like $$\{x \}$$ is a connected set in the standard topology. Also $\{x\} \times \mathbb{R}$ is connected.

But why isn't $\{ x,y \} \times \mathbb{R}$ connected? What are the two disjoint open sets such that the union is $\{ x,y \} \times \mathbb{R}$ ? I'd say that they are precisely $U = \{x\} \times \mathbb{R}$ and $V=\{y\} \times \mathbb{R}$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, assuming that $\{x, y\}$ has the discrete topology.

Comment: Thanks. One last thing, now I can't understand why "formally" $ \{ x\} \times \mathbb{R}$ is connected. What is the reason? @Magma

Comment: Think of a map $f:\{x, y\}\times\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x, r)=-1$ and $f(y, r)=1.$ Check that it is a continuous map. And conclude that $\{x, y\}\times\mathbb{R}$ is disconnected.

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho It's continuous because the preimage of open sets is open. But why are then $\{ x \} \times \mathbb{R}$ disconnected?

Comment: Try proving the following theorem: If $f: X\to \{\pm 1\}$ is a continuous surjective map, then $X$ is disconnected. The proof is pretty simple actually. You need two open disjoint sets that cover $X.$ The idea is to look at the preimages of $\pm 1$ under $f.$

Answer (score 1):

There is a single topology on $\{x\}$, so there can be no chance to get it wrong. If $B$ is any topological (or metric, if you stick with them) space, then the map
$$
f\colon B\to \{x\}\times B,\qquad b\mapsto (x,b)
$$
is easily seen to be a homeomorphism, that is, bijective, continuous and with continuous inverse. So, if $B$ is connected, also $\{x\}\times B$ is connected.

Suppose now $A$ and $B$ are nonempty topological spaces, with $A\times B$ connected. Since the map $A\times B\to A$, $(a,b)\mapsto a$ is continuous and surjective, also $A$ is connected.

Is $A=\{x,y\}$ with the discrete topology connected?

In the case of $\{x,y\}\times\mathbb{R}$, a disconnection is indeed $\{x\}\times\mathbb{R}\cup\{y\}\times\mathbb{R}$. But having a more general argument is more helpful, in my opinion.

Comment: thanks for your answer. To answer your questions: no, because singletons are open in the discrete topology and hence $A= \{x \} \cup \{y \}$, right?

Comment: @Vefhug Yes, that's correct.

Comment: thanks! @egreg One last thing: so, to show that $\{x \} \times \mathbb{R}$ is connected you suggest to use the fact that the image via a   continuous function of a connected set is connected, and the function you suggest is $$f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \{x\}\times \mathbb{R},\qquad r \mapsto (x,r)$$ I'm not sure how to show that this function is continuous... I'd just take $(a,b)$ on the line $\{x \} \times \mathbb{R}$ and the preimage is $(a,b)$ itself... so the preimage of open sets is open, and hence is continuous, right?

Comment: @Vefhug An open set in $\{x\}\times\mathbb{R}$ is of the form $\{x\}\times U$, where $U$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$, by definition of product topology.

Comment: Oops, you're right! Anyway the argument should work anyway, because the preimage of $\{x \} \times U$ via $f$ is $U$ itself, right?